# Only one instance of background task in uWSGI and gevent environment

Tags: python, uwsgi, gevent

Here is example WSGI app:

```
# coding: utf-8

from gevent import spawn, sleep, monkey; monkey.patch_all()

def app(environ, start_response):
    data = "OK\n"
    start_response("200 OK", [
        ("Content-Type", "text/plain"),
        ("Content-Length", str(len(data)))
    ])
    return iter([data])

def background_task():
    while True:
        sleep(2)
        print 'Working...'

spawn(background_task)
```

Using uwsgi with the following parameters:

```
uwsgi --gevent 1000 --processes 4 --module app --callable app --master --socket /tmp/uwsgi.sock
```

The question is how to spawn only one instance of background worker process for a multiple uWSGI processes. I need to use 4 uwsgi processes in order to achieve required performance. The main idea is to share some of the variables between the background task and the WSGI application and prevent the multiple copies of the background job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are in non-lazy mode, the "spawn()" function is only called by the master, so you are safe. If for some reason you need to move to --lazy-apps mode, just use the uwsgi.worker_id() function to know which worker is currently running, so you can do something like:

```
# spawn only if i am worker 1
if uwsgi.worker_id() == 1: spawn()
```

Comment: In my case it spawns background job for each worker.

Comment: it does not change the suggested solution. very probably your gevent hub is starting after fork so the greenlet spawn is post-poned. Just refactor your background greenlet to exit if the worker_id is not the expected one